# Bib sorting without author

Tags: bibtex, sorting

This is what one of my sources looks like

```
@misc{Madlena11, 
Author={Chavala Madlena},
Publisher={Guardian},   
Title = {Telecomix: tech support for the Arab spring}, 
url = {http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2011/jul/07/telecomix-arab-spring}
}
```

However, sometimes I have a source that doesn't have an `Author` such as:

```
@misc{RT12, 
%Author={},
Publisher={RT TV Network},   
Title = {Anti-ACTA day: Angry crowds take action}, 
url = {http://rt.com/news/acta-protests-rallies-europe-089/}
}
```

My problem is when the `Author` is not listed it doesn't sort by `Publisher` or even display the publisher in the references, nor the URL. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `key` field:

```
@misc{RT12, 
key={some string reflecting how you wish the entry alphabetized},
Publisher={RT TV Network},   
Title = {Anti-ACTA day: Angry crowds take action}, 
url = {http://rt.com/news/acta-protests-rallies-europe-089/}
}
```

Assuming you want the entry to be sorted as "RT TV Network", then use

```
key={RT TV Network}
```

The `url` field is used only if the bibliography style knows about it. For example, with

```
\usepackage[numeric]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

then URLs are showed. And the contents of `key` will be used in place of the author.

### Example

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Madlena11, 
Author={Chavala Madlena},
Publisher={Guardian},   
Title = {Telecomix: tech support for the {Arab} spring}, 
url = {http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2011/jul/07/telecomix-arab-spring}
}

@misc{RT12, 
key={aaaa},
Publisher={RT TV Network},   
Title = {{Anti}-{ACTA} day: {Angry} crowds take action}, 
url = {http://rt.com/news/acta-protests-rallies-europe-089/}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\cite{Madlena11}, \cite{RT12}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

The `filecontents*` is just for having the `.bib` file inside the source. Note also the braces to force capitalization.

[image]

Comment: Can you be a little more specific what I can use as the string for the key. Also, why would the URL not get displayed in either situation?

Comment: Also is there a similar way to display the publishers?

Comment: Unfortunately, now I do not get any errors or warnings but it still does not display the publisher. THis is what it looks like @misc{RT12, 
key={RT TV Network},
Publisher={RT TV Network},   
Title = {Anti-ACTA day: Angry crowds take action}, 
url = {http://rt.com/news/acta-protests-rallies-europe-089/}
} Also, urls are not displaying using what you have provided. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Another option (especially if you don't like having the `key` field displayed at the beginning of your entry (or at all) or have to customize each bibliographic entry to use `key` instead of `publisher`) is to customize the BST file.  Since your provided code has `natbib` using `plainnat`, you can find `plainnat.bst` in your TeX repository and place a local copy with a different name (like `plainnat-copy.bst`) into your working directory.  There are four steps in modifying your local copy of `plainnat-copy.bst`:  First, update the `misc` function to account for your usage of `publisher` instead of `howpublished`.  Second, update the `presort` function to sort by `publisher` when there is no author.  Third, write the rule for how to sort by `publisher`.  Fourth, have your TeX file use your newly customized BST file.

Note:  I am using the 2007 version of `plainnat.bst`, which is the latest as of this posting in 2022.

1. In your local copy of `plainnat-copy.bst`, search for the `misc` function and replace all instances of `howpublished` with `publisher`.  I show the new version here:

```
FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  title publisher new.block.checkb
  format.title output
  publisher new.block.checka
  publisher output
  format.date output
  format.issn output
  format.url output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
  empty.misc.check
}
```

2. Search for the `presort` function (starts with `FUNCTION {presort}`).  As you work here, note that the language in the BST file implements a postfix notation.  We'll focus just on this portion from the middle of the function:

```
        { type$ "manual" =
            'author.organization.sort
            'author.sort
          if$
        }
```

Perhaps you'll recognize that this is the innermost of a set of nested *if* statements that apply different sorting rules to different bibliographic entry types and that there is not yet a branch for the `misc` type.  By default, when the algorithm gets to this innermost *if*, the test `type$ "manual" =` returns false (because your entry is a `misc` not a `manual`) so the algorithm skips the next (first) option and applies the `author.sort` rule to all `misc` entries.  We'll modify this second option to insert the next deeper level in these nested *if* statements to establish a branch specific to `misc` entries.

```
        { type$ "manual" =
            'author.organization.sort
            { type$ "misc" =
              author empty$
              and
                'publisher.sort
                'author.sort
                if$
            }
          if$
        }
```

For anchoring, take note that the first two lines and the last two lines are the same in the original version and this modified version; I replaced only the middle line with the new code for the `misc` type.  The new logic is as follows:  If the entry is not a `manual` type, then the algorithm proceeds to the second line following, which is the next deeper level in the nested *if* statements.  Then it tests whether the type is `misc` and has no author; if both of these are true, then it will apply the `publisher.sort` rule (which we'll write in step 3 below); else it will apply the `author.sort` rule, so that all other entries are not affected by this change.

3. For the `publisher.sort` function, paste the following code into your `plainnat-copy.bst` right above the `presort` function that you just modified so that this `publisher.sort` function is between `editor.organization.sort` and `presort` functions:

```
FUNCTION {publisher.sort}
{ publisher empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need author, publisher, or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { "The " #4 publisher chop.word sortify }
  if$
}
```

4. In your TeX file, you'll need to change this line to account for your newly customized file:  `\bibliographystyle{plainnat-copy}`.  Here's the MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Madlena11, 
Author={Chavala Madlena},
Publisher={Guardian},   
Title = {Telecomix: tech support for the {Arab} spring}, 
url = {http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2011/jul/07/telecomix-arab-spring}
}

@misc{RT12, 
Publisher={RT TV Network},   
Title = {{Anti}-{ACTA} day: {Angry} crowds take action}, 
url = {http://rt.com/news/acta-protests-rallies-europe-089/}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\cite{Madlena11}, \cite{RT12}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat-copy}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Here's the output:
[image: screenshot of typeset MWE]