# Alphabetic order in bibliography with natbib package and author-less entries

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, sorting

i'm new, so I hope to do everything correctly :D

My question is fairly simple:

I've the natbib package loaded in a document, and some bibliography entries have no author. Those entries are put at the beginning of the bibliography, creating a somehow bad effect on the reader (at a first glance to the bib first page is not possible to tell the order in which the entries are presented).

Question is: how do I change it?

What I've tried so far:

- [the "key" field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX#Bibliographic_information_file): it doesn't work. The following image presents what happens if I set "key={zzzzz}" for a bibliography entry with no author:

[image]

A working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Name}
\date{Date}

\maketitle

Blah Blah \citet{aida}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{thesisbib}

\end{document}
```

with:

```
@ELECTRONIC{aida,
  year = {2011-2012},
  title = {Aida database},
  organization = {Bureau Van Dijk},
  url = {http://aida.bvdep.com},
  key = {zzzzzz}
}
```

thanks!

Comment: And where should they go instead?  At the end of the document?  (Guessing from the 'zzzzzz'....)

Comment: It seems you forgot to insert the image, showing the problem with your approach. Also please make a real MWE, i.e. remove all irrelevant classe.

Comment: Yes, I would like to put them all at the end of the bibliography.

I cannot insert the image (not enough reputation, if I understood correctly)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I propose is to use the `cite` package instead of `natbib`.

I encountered the same problem as you when citing websites. The only reason I used `natbib` was to numerically sort multiple citations ([1,3,4] instead of [3,4,1]), but the `cite` package also sorts citations.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. However i didn't mention in the question that I pretty much have to use the (author;year) citation system, does the cite package allow it?

Comment: I'd say you can achieve that by making your own bibliography style. But that may be a bit cumbersome.

Comment: Yep I think so... I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

If you must use `natbib` and `plainnat`, consider the following two options.

1. If you don't like having the `key` field displayed at the beginning of your entry (or at all) or have to customize each bibliographic entry to use `key` instead of `organization`, consider [the answer to a nearly duplicate post here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54441/bib-sorting-without-author/657104#657104) on TeX Stack Exchange describing how to customize your BST file.
2. The `\noopsort` capability may be helpful to you.  There's [discussion on it here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531322/using-noopsort-when-there-is-no-author) on TeX Stack Exchange involving a situation in which the user who initially posted the question wants to have all of the author-less bibliographic entries at the end.