# Using \noopsort when there is no author

Tags: bibtex, sorting

I added a new entry type to my book, article and incollection functions called `abbreviation`. This way, dictionaries appear in the bibliography as my publisher wants them to appear :

> TLIO = Beltrami, Pietro G./Leonardi, Lino (dir.),Tesoro della Lingua Italiana delle Origini,Florence, CNR, 1998-., [URL = http://tlio.ovi.cnr.it/TLIO].

To sort these entries alphabetically by the abbreviation, not the author, I use `@preamble{ "\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{} " }`. This all works very well, but now, I have several entries without an author :

```
@Book{ZFSL,
abbreviation = {ZFSL},
title   = {Zeitschrift für französische Sprache und Literatur},
year    = {1889–},
address = {Wiesbaden}, 
publisher   = {Steiner},
}
```

The bibliography style I wrote is based on ksfh_nat.bst and doesn't contain a `key` function. I tried to enter the `\noopsort` information with the title or the year, but it doesn't work.

Does anyone have an idea if I can get `\noopsort` to work with my `abbreviation` function or with another entry type so that I don't have to rewrite the biblioraphy style in order to include a `key` function?

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass[openany,ngerman]{book}
\usepackage[small]{dgruyter}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[main=french,italian, spanish, portuguese, latin, greek]{babel}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\defcitealias{ZFSL}{ZFSL}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
Cf. \citealis{ZFSL}\\

\bibliographystyle{Bianca}
\bibliography{bibliographie}

\end{document}
```

And you can find my bibliographystyle here : [enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yzy4zzhon75629d/Bianca.bst?dl=0)

Comment: Perhaps use the key field?

Comment: My bibliography style has no key field and I would like to find a way to omit adding this fied just because of 2 references ....