# Sorting citations and bibliography using natbib and plainnat

Tags: citing, natbib, multiple-citations

I'm writing a paper in LaTeX. I'm working with the `natbib` package and the `plainnat` style for the citations and references. The problem is how the citations and the references is being sorted.

I want the citations sorted by year (for the same year alphabeticaly) and the references sorted alphabeticaly by the author's last name. How can I do it?

My code:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage[comma,authoryear,round]{natbib}
    \usepackage[none]{hyphenat} 
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \setcitestyle{citesep={;}}

    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{A,
     author = {Ho, L. and Auntz, K. and Zwitter, B. F. and Valencia, D.},
     year = {2010},
     title = {Title Example 1},
    }
    @book{B,
     author = {Ho, L. and Yelp, A. and Richter, G. and Gregory, K. T.},
     year = {2005},
     title = {Title Example 2},
    }
    @book{C,
     author = {Ho, L. Abrook, H. and Dolman, R. G. and Fjing, H. and Ho, S. and Xerem, R.},
     year = {2013},
     title = {Title Example 3},
    }
    }
    @book{D,
     author = {Di Bernardo, L. and Mc Daug, C. and Coelho, L},
     year = {2000},
     title = {Title Example 4},
    }
    @book{E,
     author = {Gomes, L. N. L. and Ginoris, Y. P and Brand\~{a}o, C. C. S.},
     year = {2010},
     title = {Title Example 5},
    }
    \end{filecontents}


    \begin{document}
    Hi, this is an example. First a citation \citep{A,B},
then an inline citation \citet{B}.
Another citation \citep{C,D} and
the last one \citep{A,E}
    \bibliography{\jobname}
    \end{document}
```

And the result with the observations:

[image]

Comment: Would you be interested in a biblatex solution?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: How can you do this on Overleaf? My source files do not have a .bst file :(

Answer (score 6):

If you add the `sort` option to `natbib`

```
    \usepackage[sort,comma,authoryear,round]{natbib}
```

then it sorts first by author name and then by year. You seem to want to sort by year first and then author name. I don't believe `natbib` has support for that.

**Edit:** It's pretty easy to modify a copy of `plainnat.bst` to sort first by year than by name. This doesn't seem to be what you're showing in your example, but maybe it's what you want.

First, make a copy of `plainnat.bst` in your current directory and call it `yearnat.bst`. On my machine I can do that via

```
$ cp `kpsewhich plainnat.bst` yearnat.bst
```

Edit `yearnat.bst` and change the `presort` function to the following.

```
FUNCTION {presort}
{ calc.label
  label sortify
  "    "
  *
  year field.or.null sortify
  "    "
  *
  type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.sort
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.organization.sort
        { type$ "manual" =
            'author.organization.sort
            'author.sort
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
  *
  "    "
  *
  cite$
  *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.label :=
  sort.label *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.key$ :=
}
```

All this does is move the `year` field to the beginning of the sort key.

Now compile your example with the addition of the `sort` option as above and the `\bibliographystyle{yearnat}`. Here's the result.

[image]

You can see that everything is sorted first by year, and then by author. If you want to know how that works, you should read [btxhak](http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/doc/btxhak.pdf) (or by running `texdoc btxhak`).

Comment: the `sort` option sort the citations by year first as I want. But the references still are unsorted as I want

Comment: @DanielValencia No, that's not correct. `sort` puts them in the same order as the references. BibTeX (and the `.bst` used) sort the references. I don't know off-hand how the sorting is controlled, but given that different `.bst`s do it differently, you may be able to make a copy of, and edit, `plainnat.bst` to get the sorting behavior you want.

Comment: How would you modify the yearnat.bst file to sort in reverse chronological order?

Comment: @user257566, Although it would be a bit of work, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/657104/263901) may answer your question about modifying a .bst file to customize the sorting.