# How edit the `plainnat.bst` avoiding sort by key

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, sorting

I'm using `natbib` package and `plainnat` style for my citations and references. Unfortunately, when I cite different papers of the same author, but different co-authors, the bibligraphy is sorted by the key.

For example:

[image]

The key for Ho, Meyn is `Ho2006`, for Ho, Lambling is `Ho2011`, and for  Ho, Dreyfus is `Ho2012`. Certainly LaTeX is considering the keys before the second author last name.

How can I solve it???

Comment: The sorting appears to be by first author and year.

Comment: @egreg How can I sort by firs author and then second author, etc

Comment: i've never used it myself, but `custom-bib`, or the `makebst` facility, may be able to help you adjust the options you need.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments above on your original post, the MWE is necessary for others to figure out what you're trying to achieve and how you're trying to achieve it.  Without that, I cannot be sure that I'm answering your question, but I'll still provide some information here that you may find helpful.

The entries in your screenshot appear be of the `article` type.  If this is true, then `natbib` with `plainnat` will sort these articles as follows.  Note: I am using the 2007 version of `plainnat.bst`, which is the latest as of this posting in 2022.

1. The `presort` function (starting at line #1313) applies the `author.sort` rule (in line #1326).
2. The `author.sort` function (starting at line #1248) first tests whether the `author` field is empty.  Since yours are not, the function passes your `author` field to the `sort.format.names` function.
3. I pasted a copy of the `sort.format.names` function (starting at line #1207) below to assist in this explanation.  From your example above, it looks like your entries have 6, 4, or 7 authors, respectively, looking at semicolons as delimiters and a period to end the `author` block.  The code here looks to be working as you have shown in your screenshot, sorting by the first author, then the year for each of your entries.  You will notice the function referring to the `year` field, which comes into play:

   a. After sorting by the first author AND

   b. There are more authors to go other than "others" AND

   c. There are more than two authors total AND

   d. The function is on the second author (second time through the `while` loop)

   e. THEN, sort by the year.

Note that the language in the BST file implements a postfix notation.

```
FUNCTION {sort.format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  ""
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    {
      s nameptr "{vv{ } }{ll{ }}{  ff{ }}{  jj{ }}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          "   "  *
          namesleft #1 = t "others" = and
            { "zzzzz" * }
            { numnames #2 > nameptr #2 = and
                { "zz" * year field.or.null * "   " * }
                'skip$
              if$
              t sortify *
            }
          if$
        }
        { t sortify * }
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
```

Notwithstanding, there's an answer to a TeX Stack Exchange post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54441/bib-sorting-without-author/657104#657104) describing how to customize the `plainnat.bst` file to address author-less sorting.